# Javascript Loop with adding same value

Tags: javascript, loops

I hope you guys can help me!

I'm trying the following:

```
1000 + 100 = 1100 * 2 = 2200;
2200 + 100 = 2300 * 2 = 4600;
4600 + 100 = 4700 * 2 = 9400;
9400 + 100 = 9500 * 2 = 19000;
...
```

But I'm getting the flowing result.

```
1000 + 100 = 1100 * 2 = 2200;
2200 * 2 = 4400
4400 * 2 = 8800
...
```

The values are inputed by the user, but I used static values for the example.

I have te following code:

```
var generate = function generate(rate){
    var array = [];
    s=0;
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        s =+ 100;
        array.push([
            (parseInt(1000) + 100) * Math.pow(2, i),
        ]); 
    }
    return array;
}
```

Comment: `parseInt(1000)` is precisely identical to `1000`. There's no need for the call to `parseInt()`. Also, it's `+=`, not `=+`. *edit* oh wait I see, `1000` is a "static value for the example". Fair enough.

Comment: Can you describe more clearly what your input, and expected output is? Do you expect an array of numbers or just one number?

Comment: You're using `Math.pow(2, i)` but nothing in the sample formulas you posted mention anything about exponents.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like you want a function that adds 100, doubles and then calls itself recursively a fixed number of times.

This function will run 10 times and output the final answer:

```js
function add100andDouble(num, runTimes){
  if(runTimes == 0) return num;
  return add100andDouble( (num + 100 ) * 2, runTimes - 1 );
}

$(function(){
  var number = parseFloat(prompt("Enter a number"));
  alert( add100andDouble(number, 10) );
});
```

Comment: This requires jQuery.

Comment: What part of this answer requires jQuery?

Comment: The `$(function () { ... })` wrapper.

Comment: Ok so then just use `window.onload = function(){ ... }` is that really so difficult? or put it at the bottom of the body.

Comment: why would it need to be at the bottom of body, or wrapped in $() ow window.onload? does not rely on DOM readiness at all

Comment: Im assuming this will someone have to interact with the DOM otherwise this is kind of pointless.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var generate = function generate(rate){
    var array = [];
    s=0;
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        s = rate + (array[i-1] ? array[i-1] :1000);
        array.push(s*2); 
    }
    return array;
}
console.log(generate(100));
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use a function `f(x)` for calculating the new value. It makes the code more clearly arranged.

```js
function f(x) {
    return (x + 100) * 2;
}

var i = 0,
    x = 1000,
    array = [];

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    array.push(x);
    x = f(x);
}
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(array, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Recursion has its merits on other solutions but I would go with plain old for loop for this situation.

Assuming `rate` is the starting number, and the return is a fixed 10 value series:

```
function generate(rate) {
    var series = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) { 
      series.push(rate = ((rate + 100) * 2));
    };
    return series;
}
```

It can be easily modified to send the series length if needed.